# What is wrong with this code?(Polymorphism)

Tags: java, polymorphism

I tried to fix code, but I don't know how to fix it.

1. In `print` method, Write a for loop to loop through every element in the array shapes and call the method `draw`.
2. In `TestCase2` method, Call the method `print` above and pass to this method the array shapes.

   ```
   package Polymorphism.test;
   import Polymorphism.*;


   public class TestShape {


       public static void main(String[] args) {

       int testCase = 1;

       switch (testCase)
       {
           case 1:
               TestCase1();
               break;
           case 2:
               TestCase2();
               break;
           default:
               System.out.println("Invalid test case selection!");
       }

       }

       public static void print()
       {
           Shape[] shapes;
           System.out.println("Test an array of Shape:");
           for(int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++)
           {
               shapes[i].draw();
           }
       }

       public static void TestCase1()
       {
           Shape shape;

           shape = new Shape();
           shape.draw();

           shape = new Polygon();
           shape.draw();

           shape = new Rectangle();
           shape.draw();

           shape = new Square();
           shape.draw();

           shape = new Circle();
           shape.draw();
       }

       public static void TestCase2()
       {
           Shape[] shapes = {new Shape(), new Polygon(), new Rectangle(), new  Square(), new Circle(), new Polygon(), new Rectangle()};
           shapes.print();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: We are not mind readers. Post relevant parts of `Shape` please.

Comment: and what is the problem exactly ?

Comment: What is the problem? `shapes.print()` doesnt' compile? What about changing the signature of `print`to `public static void print(Shape[] shapes)`and replace the previous call by `print(shapes)` ?

Answer (score 4):

> In TestCase2 method, Call the method print above and pass to this method the array shapes

This means

```
public static void print()
```

should accept the array of Shapes :

```
public static void print(Shape[] shapes)
```

and you should pass that array to it, so change:

```
shapes.print();
```

to

```
TestShape.print(shapes);
```

You print method will become:

```
public static void print(Shape[] shapes)
{
    System.out.println("Test an array of Shape:");
    for(int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++)
    {
        shapes[i].draw();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with

```
public static void print()
{
    Shape[] shapes;
    System.out.println("Test an array of Shape:");
    for(int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++)
    {
        shapes[i].draw();
    }
}
```

You need to initialize the **shapes** array or you will get a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

You  define shapes in print, but you don't fill it:

```
public static void print()
{
    Shape[] shapes;
    System.out.println("Test an array of Shape:");

    // shapes is empty always!!!!
    for(int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++)
    {
        shapes[i].draw();
    }
}
```

Define Shape[] shapes as an attribute of your class to use it everywhere:

```
package Polymorphism.test;
import Polymorphism.*;


public class TestShape {

// declare field!!!
Shape[] shapes;


public static void main(String[] args) {

int testCase = 1;

switch (testCase)
{
    case 1:
        TestCase1();
        break;
    case 2:
        TestCase2();
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid test case selection!");


    // execute the print function
    print();
}

}

public static void print()
{
    System.out.println("Test an array of Shape:");
    for(int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++)
    {
        shapes[i].draw();
    }
}

public static void TestCase1()
{
    shapes = new Shape[5];

    shape = new Shape();
    shapes[0] = shape;

    shape = new Polygon();
    shapes[1] = shape;

    shape = new Rectangle();
    shapes[2] = shape;

    shape = new Square();
    shapes[3] = shape;

    shape = new Circle();
    shapes[4] = shape;
}

public static void TestCase2()
{
    Shape[] shapes = {
         new Shape(), new Polygon(), new Rectangle(), 
         new  Square(), new Circle(), new Polygon(),
         new Rectangle()
   };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `print()` as following:

```
public static void print(Shape [] shapes)   // HERE PASS shapes AS ARGUMENT
{
    System.out.println("Test an array of Shape:");
    for(int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++)
        {
            shapes[i].draw();
        }
    }
}
```

and `TestCase2()` as following:

```
public static void TestCase2()
{
    Shape[] shapes = {
        new Shape(), new Polygon(), new Rectangle(),
        new  Square(), new Circle(), new Polygon(),
        new Rectangle()
    };
    print(shapes); // HERE CALL STATIC METHOD
}
```